# Which is better, have a primary key composed of an integer and a foreign key or have a primary key autoincrement and a foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have a problem, the database admin have the follow structure:

[image]

As you can see the primary key of the table `TCModulo` is a composed key of the `ID_modulo` and `ID_sistema` which is a foreign key of the table `TCSistemas`.

I think that is better that the field `ID_modulo` from the table `TCModulo` must be the primary key with an auto_increment constrain, and the field `ID_sistema` must be only a foreign key.

Wich one is better?

Comment: Better in terms of what?  Database purity?  Efficiency?  Flexibility?  Cost?  Confusion?

Comment: It is not about _Wich one is better_. It is about what is the correct primary key. Does the `ID_modulo` make a primary key? If it does then it is incorrect to include the `ID_sistema` in the PK. If the `ID_sistema` is necessary to make the PK then it must be included. [Primary Key in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Primary_key)

Comment: ID_modulo could be the primary key following the other table convention, the requirement is that one system has many modules, the field ID_sistema is the primary key of the TCsistema table, so I don't understand why ID_modulo and ID_sistema is the primary key of the TCmodulo table, the db admin claim that is for data organization, talking about database purity, efficency and flelxibility

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto & kentverger: Unfortunately that wiki article is full of inaccuracies and misconceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the PK of TCmodulo is (ID_modulo) or (ID_modulo,ID_sistema) depends on what goes in the table. We cannot answer your question unless you tell us. Presumably an ID_modulo value in a row is how you refer to some modulo. You have to tell us how to do that. But after that (for every column) (and given what situations can arise) there is no choice left about which sets of columns are candidates for primary key.

A set of columns whose subrow values are unique in a table is called a superkey. Any subrow containing a unique subrow is unique. So any set of columns containing a superkey is a superkey. A subrow that contains no (smaller) unique subrow is called a candidate key. So a superkey that contains no (smaller) superkey is a candidate key. One of the candidate keys of a table is chosen as primary key.

If ID_modulo uniquely determined a module over the whole application, then (ID_modulo) would be unique with no smaller unique subrow inside so it would be a candidate key. It would be the only one so it would be the primary key.

If ID_modulo uniquely determined a module only per sistema, then (ID_modulo,ID_sistema) would be unique with no smaller unique subrow (assuming there can more than one sistemo) so it would be a candidate key. It would be the only one so it would be the primary key.

So what candidate keys are available to be chosen as primary key is up to how your application refers to modulos. After that there is no choice about candidate keys. In each of these two cases there's only one candidate key so there's no choice about primary key either.

As to whether you should have a unique id overall or only within sistema or both or anything else, that depends on other ergonomic issues. Eg you are uniquely kentverger in stackoverflow (now; user names aren't necessarily unique), but perhaps uniquely Kent at home. Eg you probably prefer to call today something like the 4th of July, rather than day 185. But note that any candidate key serves as a unique identifier. So if ID_modulo is unique only within sistema, still (ID_modula,ID_sistema) is unique overall.

Note that this has nothing to do with modulos being many-to-one with sistemas per se. It has to do with columns forming unique subrows.

Answer (score -2):

I always prefer to use an identity (auto-increment) for the primary key, as it keeps the pages clustered better and avoids fragmentation on the disk.  You need a foreign key ID_sistema anyway, so add that too.

Comment: Postgres does not have clustered indexes - and clustering by the PK is not always such a good choice anyway